# s390x images for controller node - K8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, s390x

I am trying to setup Kubernetes on a s390x machines. Having downloaded packages `kubeadm, kubectl and kubelet` specific to s390x architecture. I was under the impression that `kubeadm init` will download the control pane images for the same architecture, which proved to be incorrect.

kubeadm init seems to have downloaded `amd64` images which results in the following error `standard_init_linux.go:187: exec user process caused "exec format error`

Can someone please let me know if there are s390x specific images for the below containers, if yes please provide me the container tags or link to it please

```
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.17.2
k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.17.2
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.17.2
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.17.2
k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1
k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.3-0
k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.5
```

Comment: Hi @Ren Roz, can you put your edit as an answer please?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs we can read:

> kubeadm deb/rpm packages and binaries are built for amd64, arm (32-bit), arm64, ppc64le, and s390x following the [multi-platform proposal](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/multi-platform.md).
>
> Multiplatform container images for the control plane and addons are also supported since v1.12.
>
> Only some of the network providers offer solutions for all platforms. Please consult the list of network providers above or the documentation from each provider to figure out whether the provider supports your chosen platform.

Repo for s390x is available [here](https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-s390x).

I think it might be helpful to follow this guide for [Installing Kubernetes 1.12 on SUSE Linux using kubeadm](https://developer.ibm.com/storage/2019/03/01/kubernetes-1-12-on-suse-linux-using-kubeadm/)

Comment: Here is what I did to resolve my problem
1) Downloaded the control pane containers specific to s390x (kube-controller-manager-s390x:v1.17.2 etc..,)
2) tagged to the names in which kubeadm lookup
3) ran kubeadm init and there it is :) "Your Kubernetes control-plane has initialized successfully!
"

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem:

1. Download the control pane containers specific to s390x (kube-controller-manager-s390x:v1.17.2 etc..,)
2. Tag to the names in which `kubeadm` lookup
3. Run `kubeadm init` command

More information you can find here: [kubernestes-for-s309x](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/39229), [kubeadm-s390x](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#multi-platform).

Comment: Would you what is the equivalent for ```core-dns``` ?? 
```core-dns-s390x:1.6.5 & core-dns:1.6.5-s390x fails```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved following with the below steps:

1) Downloaded the control pane images for s390x from k8s docker repository (kube-controller-manager-s390x:v1.17.2,, likewise)
2) Had to tag the images to kube-controller-manager:v1.17.2 , because kubeadm manifests looks for this name
3) initialized my cluster and there it is " Your Kubernetes control-plane has initialized successfully! "